# logger.info() is not showing message in log file in Django project

Tags: django, logging

I am learning django logging . log files are generating but I am not showing the required message i want to show in log file. here is my code
views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.

import logging, traceback
logger = logging.getLogger('django')

def home(request):
  logger.info('Some Message')
  return render(request, 'home.html')
```

settings.py file:

```
import os

LOGGING ={
  'version':1,
  'loggers':{
    'django':{
        'handlers':['file'],
        'level':'DEBUG'
    }
 },
 'handlers':{
     'file':{
        'level':'INFO',
        'class':'logging.FileHandler',
        'filename':'./logs/debug3.log',
        'formatter':'simple'
    }
 },
  'formatters':{
    'simple':{
        'format':'{levelname} {asctime} {module} {process:d} {thread:d} {message}',
        'style':'{',
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You sure? I test your config and see in log file: INFO 2022-06-30 18:38:42,663 views 60842 140654720759552 Some Message

Comment: @Rod yes I am not seeing in my log file. is there something wrong in file path or my django version?

Comment: @Rod i have seen loggers in my log file "debug3.log" but not that specific message

Comment: The log file is created when you start web server  `python manage.py runserver` ? If not try to change the path to another, `/tmp/logs/debug3.log'

Comment: It seems that your logging config is OK, for reference I tested using v4.0.5, but I think the version is not the problem. You add the app to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py and route the view through urls.py file, so you can able to make a GET request to http:// your-server/your-path/, isn't it?

Comment: I think maybe my path is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Your logging config seems to be correct.

```
Django version 4.0.5, using settings 'proj.settings'
```

I use this for verify logging config:

proj/settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app1',  # <- example app
]

...

# Add to create the folders in Path
LOG_FILE_PATH = './logs'
LOG_FILENAME = 'debug3.log'
p = Path(LOG_FILE_PATH).resolve()
p.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers':['file'],
            'level':'DEBUG'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level':'INFO',
            'class':'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': p / LOG_FILENAME,
            'formatter':'simple'
        }
    },
    'formatters': {
        'simple': {
            'format': '{levelname} {asctime} {module} {process:d} {thread:d} {message}',
            'style': '{',
        }
    }
}
```

app1/views.py

```
from asyncio.log import logger
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.

import logging, traceback
logger = logging.getLogger('django')


def home(request):
  logger.info('Some Message')
  return HttpResponse('Home')
```

app1/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import home

urlpatterns = [
    path('', home),
]
```

proj/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('app1.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Start web server

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 --insecure
```

Go to your log file and open or tail -f

log file

```
INFO 2022-06-30 17:12:48,683 autoreload 70907 140544122230592 Watching for file changes with StatReloader
INFO 2022-06-30 17:13:03,650 views 70907 140544074688256 Some Message
INFO 2022-06-30 17:13:03,652 basehttp 70907 140544074688256 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4
```

the message is there.

Comment: Thanks mate. I just added the path once again and it worked. Thanks for your help.